# Зашифровать файл и разшифровать

Tags: c++, криптография

При расшифровке в конце файла появляются лишние символы. С чем это связано?

Исходный текст:

```
fgdhgfshgfshsfbfsjrsgjnrjtyjarjtyhjatjrgjrthrtshsehgsrhtrsthsrh
dfgdgdgf
dsgfsdg
dsfgsdfg
dsfgsdfg
sdfgsd
gadsfg
dsfg
dsfg
sfdg
fdsgsfdgsfdgdsgdsfgsdgfdsg
```

Расшифрованный текст:

```
fgdhgfshgfshsfbfsjrsgjnrjtyjarjtyhjatjrgjrthrtshsehgsrhtrsthsrh
dfgdgdgf
dsgfsdg
dsfgsdfg
dsfgsdfg
sdfgsd
gadsfg
dsfg
dsfg
sfdg
fdsgsfdgsfdgdsgdsfgsdgfdsg
dg
d
```

Код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int LFSR()
{
    static unsigned long S = 1;
    S = ((((S>>6)^(S>>5)^(S>>4)^(S>>0))&1)<<7)|(S>>1);
    return S;
}


int main()
{
    int key[255];
    for(int i = 0;i < 255;++i)
        key[i] = LFSR();
    for(int i = 0;i < 255;++i)
        cout<<key[i]<<endl;

    int s;
    //Открыаем файл в двоичном режиме
    fstream text("text.txt", ios_base::binary|ios_base::in);
    fstream chiper("chiper.txt", ios_base::binary|ios_base::out);

    //Проверили файл на открытие
    if(!text.is_open() && !chiper.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Файл не может быть открыт!\n";
        return 0;
    }

    //Зашифровка
    int i = 0;
    while(!text.eof())
    {
        text.read((char*)&s,sizeof(s));
        s = s^key[i];
        chiper.write((char*)&s,sizeof(s));
        ++i;
        if(i==255)
            i=0;
    }
    text.close();
    chiper.close();
/*-----------------------------------------------------------*/
    chiper.open("chiper.txt",ios_base::binary|ios_base::in);
    fstream dechiper("dechiper.txt", ios_base::binary|ios_base::out);

    if(!dechiper.is_open() && !chiper.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Файл не может быть открыт!\n";
        return 0;
    }

    //Расшифровка
    i = 0;
    while(!chiper.eof())
    {
        chiper.read((char*)&s,sizeof(s));
        s = s^key[i];
        dechiper.write((char*)&s,sizeof(s));
        ++i;
        if(i==255)
            i=0;
    }
    chiper.close();
    dechiper.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не сильно вдавался в алгоритм, но вы попробуйте заменить `int s` на `char s`, или вместо `sizeof(s)` везде писать `sizeof(char)`

Comment: слышком все усложняете, а потом ищете ошибку.  Почему не писать проще и лучше?..

Comment: Ну так ты расскажи как писать проще и лучше. Я же не просто так спрашиваю

Comment: @selya все равно появляются только другие

Comment: ваш вопрос заключается в нахождении ошибки в коде,но мне так не понравился ваш код, что я решил дать вам совет искать путь лучше. Я не ответил на ваш вопрос и не собираюсь.  А если я напишу другой код, то это не будет являться ответом на ваш вопрос

Comment: @ARHovsepyan 
1) Я не прошу писать код, я прошу лишь объяснить, то что возможно я не учел при работе с файлами
2) Вам не нужно читать весь код, только те места где идет работа с файлами(как мне кажется, полный код я дал лишь для полноты картины)
3) Вам не понравился мой код? Код должен нравится? Искать путь лучше? Может подскажите в какую сторону идти?
4) Ну напишите другой код может это мне поможет

Comment: А, так метод `write` же принимает номер символов, сколько надо записать. Соответственно, поставьте там 1. И почитайте справку про метод `read`, может тоже полезно будет

Comment: В любом случае EOF возникает при вызове read. Поэтому после него (а не перед (у вас в `while`)) всегда надо проверять, не достигнут ли конец файла.

Comment: @avp действительно в этом и была проблема. Спасибо вам

Comment: @PeWpIC, например:   храните в    unordered_map<int, string>  table целое, генерирумой 
 какой то функцией и   строку, которую считываете из файла.  В этом же цикле записывайте в файл  для записи  эти числа,   При расшифровке читайте эти числа  'n' из файла и table[n] записывйте в результирующий файл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем то ответ дал @avp за что ему огромное спасибо.

добавил проверку на конец файла после read
Кусок подправленного кода:

```
while(!text.eof())
    {
        text.read((char*)&s,sizeof(char));
        if(text.eof())
            break;
        cout << s;
        s = s^key[i];
        chiper.write((char*)&s,sizeof(char));
        ++i;
        if(i==255)
            i=0;
    }
```